# spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\bin ENOENT

Tags: node.js, npm, cmd, npx

hope all is well.

I am trying to run the wizard from https://github.com/0xProject/0x-launch-kit. I have successfully downloaded Node.js, Yarn, Docker and npx but after running the following command
`npx @0x/launch-kit-wizard && docker-compose up`

I am receiving spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\bin ENOENT .

I have already gone to computer>properties>Advance System Settings>Environment Variables> and added the required C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\bin to path and ComSpec but i am getting still the same error.

Would really appreciate some help.

Thank you

Comment: `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe` is not a searchable path. It's a program file.

Comment: The value of `%ComSpec%` is generally supposed to be a `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`, not a semicolon delimited list of file and directory paths. BTW, to clarify the previous comment, please remove `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe` from your `%PATH%` variable value.

Comment: Thank you Compo !! That actually worked :)

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue, and it turns out that one of my container images was connecting to an old path on my local machine, once I corrected that, everything started working again.

Another tip is to first ensure your docker is updated to the latest version.

Secondly, don't run the entire container at once, but rather run each of its images (sub containers) one by one, till they are all running to determine which image is breaking, which is how I found my offending image, hope this helps.

[image: example of Docker Error 1]

[image: example of Docker Error 2]

[image: start each of the container parts one by one, to determine where the issue is]

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I updated docker to the latest version. And then it gave me more appropriate error message which resulted in solving the issue.

Comment: For me, the problem got sorted, when I updated docker desktop...

Answer (score 0):

Run each sub container images one by one.